# Add a field to a child DataSet C# using Rows.add & adapter.update

Tags: c#, database, dataset

I added some data to a parent DataSet and need to add something to a child table. Everything is ok except I need a number of a row form the parent table (the one I just added). So, **I did adapter.update for the parent table** and when I try to get

`ds.tables["Parent"].rows[ds.tables["parent"].rows.count-1][0]`

it gives me null. Is it possible to get the last number from the parent table?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved my problem by disposing BbConnection and creating it again. (I don't want to deal with it write now but I disposed and recreated everything including DataSet and Adapters). So looks like

`adapter.update(dataset,table_name);`

will update a record you just added either after adding another record or after restarting the program. So in my case I needed to add a record to a parent table and several depended records to a child table inferring to the last record from the parent table. Another solution of course is to avoid relations but I wanted to have a program with them.

**If anyone has better solution I will be happy to learn it.**